# Use an optionally passed-in block without repeating yourself

Tags: ruby, lambda

I need to open and read several files for a project. Some of them are plain text files, and I just want a standard `File.open` to read from. One of them is an XML file, and I want it automatically loaded into Nokogiri in the following way:

`xml = File.open("#{LOCATION}/#{filename}.xml"){|f| Nokogiri::XML(f){|config| config.noblanks}}`

So I created a function that takes a pattern to select a file, and then optionally opens it with a block so that I can pass in the `Nokogiri` block above in the case of the xml file.

How do I reduce the repetition in the code?

```
# in read_xml...
xml = file_from_pattern(XML_PATTERN){|f| Nokogiri::XML(f){|config| config.noblanks}}

# in read_audit...
audit_lines = file_from_pattern(AUDIT_PATTERN).readlines


def file_from_pattern(pattern)
  file_name = Dir.entries("#{LOCATION}").select{|f| f =~ pattern}[0]
  if block_given?
    yield File.open("#{LOCATION}/#{file_name}")
  else
    File.open("#{LOCATION}/#{file_name}")
  end
end
```

Comment: I recognize I can use a ternary to shorten this up but I had it expanded so it was easier to read for this question.

Answer (score 4):

Some notes:

- `select {... }[0]` -> `detect { ... }`.
- Is `LOCATION` a string? Then, `"#{LOCATION}"` -> `LOCATION`
- Use `File#join` instead of manual string manipulation.
- The only repetition in your code is `File.open("#{LOCATION}/#{file_name}")`. The solution is very simple: create a local variable and use it.
- Don't you check whether `file_name` is `nil`?
- `File#open` accepts a block, why don't you simply pass it? you get the file descriptor closed for free in the block case.

I'd write:

```
def file_from_pattern(pattern, &block)
  file_name = Dir.entries(LOCATION).detect { |f| f =~ pattern }
  if file_name
    # Refactor 1:
    # fd = File.open(File.join(LOCATION, file_name))
    # block_given? ? yield(fd) : fd
    File.open(File.join(LOCATION, file_name), &block)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, these are some really good comments - the `"#{LOCATION}"` one in particular was painfully obvious :(.

Comment: Noone said `LOCATION` is a string, so `"#{LOCATION}"` -> `LOCATION.to_s`

Comment: I'd take your insight "`File#open` accepts a block, why don't you simply pass it?" to it's logical conclusion: The "finding a file from a directory using a pattern" and the "post-processing after its opened" steps shoudn't be coupled in the first place.  Even the name `file_from_pattern` suggests that the coupling is wrong.  Let `file_from_pattern` get a file from a pattern.  Then use the built in block of `File#open` to do the post-processing.

Comment: @Jonah: Good point, there should be a method just for filtering. But IMO you can still have another one that combines filtering+opening and works as the OP asked for.

Comment: True enough, and depending on further context it might be a good idea.  Knowing just what we know here though I don't think it buys us much